# Google Analytics API related products

Tags: c#, .net, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I trying to get data from analytics for Related Products table. API throw exception:

```
{"Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
    No such dimension(s): 
        ga:correlationModelId, ga:queryProductId, 
        ga:queryProductVariation, ga:relatedProductId, 
        ga:queryProductName, ga:relatedProductVariation, 
        ga:relatedProductName
    No such metric(s): 
        ga:queryProductQuantity, ga:correlationScore, ga:relatedProductQuantity 
[400]
    Errors [
        Message[
    No such dimension(s): 
        ga:correlationModelId, ga:queryProductId,
        ga:queryProductVariation, ga:relatedProductId,
        ga:queryProductName, ga:relatedProductVariation,
        ga:relatedProductName
    No such metric(s): 
        ga:queryProductQuantity, ga:correlationScore,
        ga:relatedProductQuantity
        ] 
    Location[ - ] Reason[badRequest] Domain[global]
  ]"}
```

When I turn on "ecommerce" in google analytics admin this error is not raised. How to determine programmatically this option and enable it (if turned off)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine the status via the Google Analytics Management API, specifically via the [View-Methods](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles) "get" (which will return a [resource](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles#resource) that contains the ""eCommerceTracking" and "enhancedECommerceTracking" properties (you are looking for the latter, I don't think related product exist in standard e-commerce tracking) and the "update"-Method which allows you to set the values for these properties (I don't know C#, so alas no language specific example).

However I'm not sure why you want to set this - it's not like there will suddenly be data in the (related) products if there hasn't been eccommerce-Tracking and if you enable it you need to change the tracking code and do additional configuration. I would suggest you simply catch the exception, which after all gives you the same information (i.e. there is no data).

Comment: I'm find this option. Thanks!